# Clear javascript on dynamic load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

I have a javascript plugin for a special image scroller. The scroller contains a bunch of timeout methods and a lot of variables with values set from those timeouts.

Everything works perfectly, but for the site I am working on it is required that the pages are loaded dynamically. The problem with this is when i for instance change the language on the site this is made by jquery load function meaning the content is dynamically loaded onto the site - AND the image slider aswell.

NOW here is the big problem! When I load the image slider for the second time dynamically all my previous values remains as well as the timers and everything else. **Is there any way to clear everything in the javascript plugin as if it where like a page reload?**

I have tried a lot of stuff so far so a little help would be much appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post some code? A picture says more than thousand words. ;-)

Comment: Can't say much without seeing your code, but you might want to create a scope to "contain" your settings.

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like that to reload scripts:

```
<script class="persistent" type="text/javascript">      
  function reloadScripts()
  { [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('script:not(.persistent)'), function(oldScript)
    { 
      var newScript = document.createElement('script');

      newScript.text = oldScript.text;
      for(var i=0; i<oldScript.attributes.length; i++)
        newScript.setAttribute(oldScript.attributes[i].name, oldScript.attributes[i].value);

      oldScript.parentElement.replaceChild(newScript, oldScript);
    });
  }

  // test
  setInterval(reloadScripts, 5000);
</script>
```

As far as I know, there's no other way to reset a script than completely remove the old one and create another one with the same attributes and content. Not even clone the node would reset the script, at least in Firefox.

You said you want to reset timers. Do you mean `clearTimeout()` and `clearInterval()`? The methods `Window.prototype.setTimeout()` and `Window.prototype.setInterval()` both return an ID wich is to pass to a subsequent call of `clearTimeout()`. Unfortunately there is no builtin to clear any active timer.

I've wrote some code to register all timer IDs. The simple TODO-task to implement a wrapper callback for setTimeout is open yet. The functionality isn't faulty, but excessive calls to setTimeout could mess up the array.

Be aware that extending prototypes of host objects can cause undefined behavior since exposing host prototypes and internal behavior is not part of specification of W3C. Browsers could change this future. The alternative is to put the code directly into window object, however, then it's not absolutely sure that other scripts will call this modified methods. Both decisions are not an optimal choice.

```
  (function()
  { // missing in older browsers, e.g. IE<9
    if(!Array.prototype.indexOf)
      Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'indexOf', {value: function(needle, fromIndex)
      { // TODO: assert fromIndex undefined or integer >-1
        for(var i=fromIndex || 0; i < this.length && id !== window.setTimeout.allIds[i];) i++;
        return i < this.length ? i : -1;
      }});

    if(!Array.prototype.remove)
      Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'remove', { value: function(needle) 
      { var i = this.indexOf(needle);
        return -1 === i ? void(0) : this.splice(i, 1)[0]; 
      }});


    // Warning: Extensions to prototypes of host objects like Window can cause errors
    //          since the expose and behavior of host prototypes are not obligatory in
    //          W3C specs.
    //          You can extend a specific window/frame itself, however, other scripts
    //          could get around when they call window.prototype's methods directly.
    try
    {
      var
        oldST = setTimeout,
        oldSI = setInterval,
        oldCT = clearTimeout,
        oldCI = clearInterval
      ;
      Object.defineProperties(Window.prototype, 
      {
        // TODO: write a wrapper that removes the ID from the list when callback is executed
        'setTimeout':
        { value: function(callback, delay)
          {
            return window.setTimeout.allIds[window.setTimeout.allIds.length]
              = window.setTimeout.oldFunction.call(this, callback, delay);
          }
        },

        'setInterval':
        { value: function(callback, interval)
          {
            return window.setInterval.allIds[this.setInterval.allIds.length]
              = window.setInterval.oldFunction.call(this, callback, interval);
          }
        },

        'clearTimeout':
        { value: function(id)
          { debugger;
            window.clearTimeout.oldFunction.call(this, id);
            window.setTimeout.allIds.remove(id);
          }
        },

        'clearInterval':
        { value: function(id)
          {
            window.clearInterval.oldFunction.call(this, id);
            window.setInterval.allIds.remove(id);
          }
        },

        'clearTimeoutAll' : { value: function() { while(this.setTimeout .allIds.length) this.clearTimeout (this.setTimeout .allIds[0]); } },
        'clearIntervalAll': { value: function() { while(this.setInterval.allIds.length) this.clearInterval(this.setInterval.allIds[0]); } },
        'clearAllTimers'  : { value: function() { this.clearIntervalAll(); this.clearTimeoutAll(); } }
      });

      window.setTimeout   .allIds      = [];
      window.setInterval  .allIds      = [];
      window.setTimeout   .oldFunction = oldST;
      window.setInterval  .oldFunction = oldSI;
      window.clearTimeout .oldFunction = oldCT;
      window.clearInterval.oldFunction = oldCI;
    } 
    catch(e){ console.log('Something went wrong while extending host object Window.prototype.\n', e); }
  })();
```

This puts a wrapper method around each of the native methods. It will call the native functions and track the returned IDs in an array in the `Function` objects of the methods. Remember to implement the TODOs.